# Qual a forma correta de escrever "14" por extenso?

Tags: ortografia, diferenças

Qual é a forma correta para escrever (por extenso) 14? *Catorze* ou *Quatorze*?

Comment: Eu sempre escrive _catorze_, porque parece mais normal.

Comment: Eu sempre escrevi "quatorze". Por que parece mais normal... É relativo a região que vivemos.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim...

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Quatorze também faz sentido, já que a seguir vem _quinze_.

Comment: Acho muito mais bonito quatorze. Dá um ar sofisticado e afrancesado ao português, tanto na versão brasileira quanto no português europeu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tanto `Catorze` quanto `Quatorze` existem na lingua portuguesa e estão corretas.

Podemos usar as palavras quatorze ou catorze sempre que quisermos referir o numeral cardinal 14

> **Quatorze** tem sua origem na palavra em latim `quattuordecim`, mantendo sua escrita com **qu**.
>
> **Catorze** também tem sua origem na palavra em latim `quattuordecim`, mas sofreu alteração de **qu** para **c**, ou seja, *sofreu uma adequação ortográfica baseada na fonética da sílaba*.

**Exemplos**

- Quatorze casais participarão no encontro.
- Catorze casais participarão no encontro.
- Depois do número quatorze vem o número quinze.
- Depois do número catorze vem o número quinze.

> **NOTA:** Existem, na língua portuguesa, palavras que apresentam mais do que uma grafia correta. A estas palavras chamamos formas gráficas variantes. Embora haja sempre uma forma preferida e mais utilizada pelos falantes, todas as formas são corretas.

Nos documentos oficiais da União Europeia consta:

> catorze com «c» (e não quatorze, como no Brasil);
> Ref: http://publications.europa.eu/code/pt/pt-4100900pt.htm

Obrigado: @AméricoTavares

Comment: Nos documentos oficiais da UE só se usa catorze,  segundo a página http://publications.europa.eu/code/pt/pt-4100900pt.htm

Comment: Para verbos com múltiplas formas há o termo "verbos abundantes" (ex trazido/trago), há uma terminologia comum para palavras com múltiplas grafias, ou para cada classe gramatical há um termo diferente? "Formas gráficas variantes" podem ser aplicadas a verbos?

Comment: "e não quatorze, como no Brasil"   Ei, do lado de cá usa-se muito o "catorze".  Eu mesmo sempre escrevi assim.