# Concactenar ou Concatenar?

Tags: ortografia

Na área da programação costumamos usar o termos *"concat"* (inglês) ou *"concatenar"*, no entanto já vi escrito *conca**c**tenar*, com `C` antes de `T`.

O uso da palavra *conca**c**tenar* é correto? Seria um neologismo?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta não traz valor acrescentado à comunidade (é superficial, e não é útil). http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/sobre-quest%C3%B5es-superficiais/80#80

Comment: A palavra vem do latim e há ocorrências dela na língua desde o século XIX (sem o **c**, que a resposta abaixo já explicou que é um erro). Ou seja, não é um neologismo, estou removendo a tag.

Comment: @ANeves Muitas das perguntas aqui no site tem o mesmo principio e ao meu ver o nosso site pode ser uma fonte de pesquisa e foi este o motivo de criar a pergunta, e semelhante a esta situação http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/60/8

Comment: `Muitas das perguntas aqui no site têm o mesmo princípio`: algumas ([1](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/65/como-escrever-estrupo-ou-estupro), [2](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/19/qual-%C3%A9-a-forma-correta-para-escrever-por-extenso-14-catorze-ou-quatorze), [3](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/981/viagem-ou-viajem), etc) acho que não trazem valor acrescentado; outras ([1](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/108/quando-usar-aonde-ou-onde), [2](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8/157l)) acho valiosas (mas algumas podem ser melhoradas).

Comment: Eu percebo isso; mas discordo sobre o valor acrescentado que elas trazem (ou não) ao site. Sugiro discutir isso **[no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio)**.

Comment: (O meu comentário à pergunta foi discutido [no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23715213#23715213).)

Answer (score 8):

Como o @BrunoLopes comentou, a palavra `concactenar` **não existe** no Português de Portugal (Português Europeu).

Uma pequena pesquisa aos dicionários de Português de Portugal demonstraram que a palavra `concactenar` não existe mas sim a palavra `concatenar`.

- [Priberam Dicionário](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Concactenar)
- [Infopédia (Dicionários Porto Editora) com o novo Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/concactenar)
- [Infopédia sem o novo Acordo Ortográfico](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/Concactenar)

---

Para além disso, **o Português de Portugal** conta com um novo [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990), que entrou em vigor a [13 de maio de 2009](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990#Resumo_da_situa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_nos_pa.C3.ADses_e_regi.C3.B5es_lus.C3.B3fonos), o qual apresenta uma mudança notável na manutenção de certas consoantes após as letras `a,e,o` em palavras como `Egipto, actor, electricidade` etc.

Basicamente, estas palavras perdem as suas consoantes pois as mesmas não são pronunciadas, ficando então da seguinte forma: `Egito, ator, eletricidade`.

Em relação à palavra `facto`, esta mantém-se pois o "c" **é pronunciado**.

Comment: Na realidade, a palavra _concactenar_ nunca existiu. Trata-se apenas de um erro ortográfico.