# Como escrever: Estrupo ou estupro?

Tags: ortografia

Muitas pessoas enganam-se ao pronunciar isso, e fiquei em dúvida sobre qual a forma correta de escrever e pronunciar, estrupo ou estupro?

Comment: -1: Não tem acesso a nenhum dicionário?? Nem físico nem online?

Comment: Se for assim, podes dar -1 em todas as questões, com o critério de "Não tem acesso a internet?", cada panaca

Comment: 1. Tenta ser construtivo em vez de ofensivo; assim evitas fazer más figuras. 2. Não considero a pergunta útil nem para quem pergunte, nem para quem use o site; dá menos trabalho consultar o dicionário do que escrever a pergunta, que diabo...

Comment: Opinião tua, não eres dono da verdade, por enquanto 1 pessoa não gostou e 4 sim, não ta satisfeito, cria um novo site, ou ocupa teu tempo respondendo as questões em aberto. Essa pergunta é do primeiro dia do site, de quando varias perguntas simples como essa surgiram. 90% das questões do site estão em outras paginas da web, logo não teria necessidade desse existir, em momento algum foi sitado para não fazer perguntas simples ou que não existam em outros sites, to nem ai com o que pensam de minha figura, para pessoas chatas se corta logo o assunto, queres dar -1 tudo bem, mas acha um motivo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segue definição:

**Estrupo** – Barulho alto.

**Estupro** – ato de violência sexual considerado crime.