# Quando usar "aonde" ou "onde"?

Tags: gramática, advérbios

Existe uma confusão no uso das palavras *onde* e *aonde*. Quando devo utilizá-las?

Exemplos:

- *Aonde você vai?* ou *Onde você vai?*
- *Aonde fica o Cristo Redentor?* ou *Onde fica o Cristo Rendeiro?*

Comment: Falta aqui uma resposta mais completa.

Answer (score 11):

*Aonde* = *para onde*. No exemplo que você deu, *Aonde você vai?*

*Onde* = *em qual lugar*. No exemplo que você deu, *Onde fica o Cristo Redentor?*

[(Fonte)](http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/noticias/aonde-ou-onde-como-usar)

Answer (score 10):

Observe que ambos os termos são [advérbios de lugar](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/adverbios-lugar/), expressam a ideia de um local ou posicionamento.

[Onde](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/onde) traz o significado de "*em qual lugar*", podendo ser utilizado também para se referir a um termo anterior na frase funcionando de modo similar a "*que*" com função de [pronome relativo](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint39.php).

> Onde estou?
>
> Onde você vai morar?
>
> "O meu lugar é onde você quer que ele seja."
>
> Moro em uma cidade onde as pessoas não são loucas.

[Aonde](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/aonde) traz o significado de "*para qual lugar*", "*para onde*"; pode ser considerado como a simples junção da [preposição](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/preposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o) **a** ao advérbio **onde** (a + onde = aonde). Portanto será usado para indicar movimento, transmitindo a ideia de lugar para o qual se vai.

> Aonde eu vou?
>
> Aonde você foi ontem?
>
> Não te interessa aonde vou.
>
> "Todos os caminhos estão errados quando você não sabe aonde quer chegar."

Answer (score 6):

As outras respostas refletem bem as abordagens prescritivas para este assunto. Mas a prática raramente as segue.

Aliás, no meio onde vivi (entre pessoas com alguma educação em Lisboa), **onde** é usado na maioria das situações em que se poderia (porventura deveria...) usar *aonde*. Uma frase como *Onde é que vais?* é muito mais comum do que *Aonde é que vais?*

Já **aonde** é mais raro e, quando é usado, não é feita a distinção prescrita. É-o tanto para direção como para significar *o lugar em que*, mas soa mais popular. E por muito que se queira insistir que *aonde* indica uma direção, a verdade é que o seu uso noutras situações está mais que consagrado na literatura (desde Camões a Fernando Pessoa).

Sobre o assunto diz a gramática de Cunha e Cintra:

> Embora a ponderável razão de maior clareza idiomática justifique o contraste que a disciplina gramatical procura estabelecer, na língua culta contemporânea, entre *onde* (= o lugar em que) e *aonde* (= o lugar a que), cumpre ressaltar que essa distinção, praticamente anulada na linguagem coloquial, já não era rigorosa nos clássicos.

Para além de a distinção presecrita entre *onde* e *aonde* não existir na prática, confirma a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian a referida preferência das camadas cultas por *onde* (p. 2103):

> Os falantes mais cultos consideram a forma *aonde* (e *adonde*) marginal, correspondendo a um uso mais popular, e preferem a forma *onde*, independentemente do valor locativo associado. [...] [nota de rodapé: [A norma linguística de distinção entre *onde* e *aonde*] é relativamente recente, a avaliar pela descrição de Saudi Ali, que a situa no português moderno. Talvez o seu caráter recente esteja por detrás da recusa das camadas mais cultas em aceitar a forma *aonde*, em tempos considerada marginal.]

Ainda assim, os autores defendem que *aonde* é usado nalgumas circunstâncias, embora não por motivos relacionados com a dita regra e creiam que não seja um verdadeiro *aonde*. Continua:

> No entanto, mesmo para alguns destes falantes, o uso das duas formas em orações relativas com antecedente implícito não é tão livre quanto possa parecer pelos outros contextos.
>   Assim, quando o antecedente é explícito, se a construção relativa (recorda-se: o sintagma nominal que contém o antecedente - implícito, neste caso - e a oração relativa) estiver integrada num constituinte com valor locativo dinâmico de destino (valor esse determinada na oração principal), a forma *onde* é considerada estranha pelos falantes, mesmo que o constituinte relativo tenha um valor estático na oração relativa:
>   (i) a.    No domingo vamos *aonde nos conhecemos* _.
>         b. ??No domingo vamos *onde nos conhecemos* _.
>   Em contrapartida, se a construção relativa estiver associada a um valor locativo estático na oração principal, *onde* é preferível a *aonde*, mesmo que o constituinte relativo tenha um valor locativo de destino na oração relativa:
>   (ii) a.   No domingo estivemos *onde tu foste _ no verão*.
>         b. ?No domingo estivemos *aonde tu foste _ no verão*.
>   Para estes falantes, a alternância condicionada entre *onde* e *aonde* nestes contextos parece ser determinada pelo valor semântico da construção relativa na oração principal. Assim, quando este valor é dinâmico, de destino, como em (i) (neste caso determinado pelo verbo *ir*), a forma preferida  *aonde*, independentemente do valor locativo do pronome na oração relativa.

A explicação será esta:

> Ao valor locativo de destino está associada a preposição *a*, enquanto ao valor locativo estático está associada a preposição *em*, não ocorrendo esta última quando o locativo corresponde ao pronome relativo *onde*. Em (ia), apesar de haver uma fusão fonética e ortográfica da preposição *a* com o pronome, o constituinte relativo é apenas *onde*, visto que a preposição pertence, na realidade, à oraçào principal, sendo selecionada pelo verbo *ir*; ou seja, a preposição introduz o antecedente implícito da oração relativa [marcado a seguir por _]: *a _ [[onde] ...]* cf. ***a**o lugar **onde**...* Portanto, é natural que mesmo falantes que associam a forma *aonde* a registos mais populares prefiram (ia) e rejeitem (ib), pois aqui não se trata de variação lexical entre os pronomes *onde* e *aonde*, mas sim da aplicação de um requisito que condiciona a estrutura da frase. Esses mesmos falantes rejeitarão totalmente (iib), da mesma forma que rejeitam orações como *aonde foste?*.

Comment: Excelente ponto a ser feito. Uso popular e licença poética.