# Viagem ou viajem?

Tags: ortografia, verbos

A palavra **viajem** existe?

- Será uma escrita alternativa para *viagem*?
- Será uma forma do verbo *viajar*?

Se existe, qual é a diferença entre "viajem" e "viagem"?

Comment: Não me parece claro qual é a dúvida. É sobre se o substantivo pode ser escrito com j? É sobre se a palavra viajem existe? Ou outra?

Comment: É sobre a existência e emprego da palavra "viajem". Corrigi a pergunta.

Comment: Fiz uma sugestão de edição, que acho que torna a pergunta mais clara. Mas a pergunta não me parece útil (mesmo com a edição).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Viagem** é o substantivo, cujo significado é

> 1. O ato de transportar-se de um ponto a outro distante.
> 2. [Marinha]  Navegação, travessia.
> 3. Percurso efetuado.
> 4. Relação escrita dos acontecimentos ocorridos numa viagem e das impressões que ela causou.
> 5. [Informal]  Estado alucinatório provocado pelo consumo de certas drogas.

Fonte: [Significado / definição de viagem no Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/viagem)

Já **viajem** é uma forma conjugada do verbo **viajar**. Exemplo:

> Espero que eles **viajem** bem.

Answer (score 6):

A palavra *viajem* existe. Ela é o verbo *viajar* conjugado na 3ª pessoa do plural do Presente Subjuntivo de viajar (http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/viajar). Desta forma, também é forma imperativa. Sendo assim, ela tem dois usos:

- Subjuntivo - Quando o verbo integra uma oração subordinada: *"Eu não quero que eles viajem para a praia"*
- Imperativo - Aqui vale ressaltar que os pronomes de tratamento (*você* e *vocês*) são de 3ª pessoa, e não de 2ª pessoa. Então a forma imperativa *viajem* é usada para dar uma ordem a várias pessoas usando "*vocês*": *"Se vocês querem ganhar o emprego na capital, então viajem para lá!"*

Answer (score 5):

Este fenômeno sempre acontece na língua portuguesa: a etimologia de *viagem* (vindo de *viatge*) exige que o som seja suave, mas na combinação do sufixo *-ar* com o radical *viag-*, o som produzido (*viagar*) não seria suave e o *g* é substituido por *j*, dando *via**j**ar*.

Isto é a fonte das formas irregulares de verbos regulares, como *fi**c**ar* → *fi**qu**ei*, etc.

Não faz sentido reverter este processo e assumir que a existência do verbo *viajar* implique a existência de um substantivo *viajem*.

No caso da combinação *viag-* + *-ear*, o resultado não precisaria da substituição *g* → *j*, dando *via**g**ear*; mas *viag-* + *-ante* precisa, resultando em *via**j**ante*.

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado pela correção!

Comment: Sempre às ordens! Aprendi alguma coisa com a tua resposta.